# Why is Stop Iteration being raised in this code?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why is `StopIteration` being raised. My understanding is that when `nos` reaches `9`, the `if` statement evaluates to `True`. After that, `print(next(generate_nos([0, 1, …, 9])))` is called, which should result in `0` as the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
nos = (i for i in range(10))


def generate_nos(mynos):
    for i in mynos:
        yield i * 2

try:
    while(1):
        if next(generate_nos(nos)) == 18:
            print(next(generate_nos(nos)))
except StopIteration:
    print("StopIteration")
```

Comment: There is no sense in `nos = (i for i in range(10))`, when you can simply `nos = range(10)` instead.

Comment: Also, `while(1):` can be `while 1:`, or even better (and clear), `while True:`.

Comment: @accdias : `range(10)` gives an object of type `range` ( `type(range(10)) #> <class 'range'>` ). `(i for i in range(10))` gives an object of type `generator` ( `type((i for i in range(10))) #> <class 'generator'>`. So `nos = range(10)` produces another result not being fully equivalent to `nos = (i for i in range(10))`, right?

Comment: Yep... but that is not relevant for the question. A `range()` object will work just fine, and it is more clear IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can only use a generator once. You exhausted it by looping until it yielded 18. Then you tried to get it to yield another element inside the `print` statement.

If you are using python 3.8+, you might want to use the walrus operator to assign the yielded element to a variable so you can print it:

```
nos = (i for i in range(10))


def generate_nos(mynos):
    for i in mynos:
        yield i*2

try:
    while(1):
        if (elem := next(generate_nos(nos))) == 18:
            print(elem)
except StopIteration:
    print("StopIteration")
```

This prints `18`, but then also prints `StopIteration`, because you never actually stopped the iteration -- the `while` loop continued to ask for the next element. A simple `break` after the `print` would do the job.

If you have python < 3.8, you'll need to split the assignment to `elem` and the comparison to `18` into two lines:

```
try:
    while(1):
        elem = next(generate_nos(nos))
        if elem == 18:
            print(elem)
            break
except StopIteration:
    print("StopIteration")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why is Stop Iteration being raised in this code?*

The actual question is from my perspective why do *you* expect that `StopIteration` shouldn't be raised?

I suppose from what you write about your understanding of what should happen that you expect that with each call to `generate_nos(nos)` the generator function starts from the beginning of the in this function defined loop. But `nos` passed to this function is a global scope generator object. So you use a generator object to get next value of `i`. The generator object does not deliver all of its values on a call which is done while running the `for i` loop. It delivers values one after another. In other words wrapping a generator object with a generator function which iterates over the generator object items results in delivering the items exactly the same way as without the wrapper because of the "lazy" character of the generator where you can't expect in advance to know how much items it will deliver - you know it earliest at the time of running into `StopIteration`. Probably you have expected that wrapping a generator with a generator function using a loop over the generator object items will result in re-running the generator object. But you use a global scope generator object which once exhausted does not re-initiate itself, but stays exhausted all the time for any further request for delivering the next item. To put all of the above said into one short sentence may look like:

*`StopIteration` propagates through all of the generator functions wrapping a generator object.*

The code you have provided is a perfect case where using *print debugging* can step by step make clear what actually is happening in order to detect where it deviates from what has been expected:

```
nos = (i for i in range(10))
print(f"nos = (i for i in range(10)) results in: {nos=}")

def generate_nos(mynos):
    print(f"            CALL of generate_nos({mynos=}):")
    for i in mynos:
        print(f"                for i in mynos: {i=}, {i*2=}  (next line: yield i*2)")
        yield i * 2

try:
    while(1):
        nextGen = next(generate_nos(nos)) 
        print(f'    INSIDE while(1):  {nextGen=} == next(generate_nos(nos)')
        if nextGen == 18:
            print("        if nextGen == 18:")
            print(next(generate_nos(nos)))
except StopIteration:
    print(f"StopIteration:  {nos=}")

> python3 -u "whyStopIteration.py"
# nos = (i for i in range(10)) results in: nos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=0, i*2=0  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=0 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=1, i*2=2  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=2 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=2, i*2=4  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=4 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=3, i*2=6  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=6 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=4, i*2=8  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=8 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=5, i*2=10  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=10 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=6, i*2=12  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=12 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=7, i*2=14  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=14 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=8, i*2=16  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=16 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
#                 for i in mynos: i=9, i*2=18  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=18 == next(generate_nos(nos)
#         if nextGen == 18:
#             CALL of generate_nos(mynos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>):
# StopIteration:  nos=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbe4016a420>
# > exit status: 0
```

Now back to answering your question:

`StopIteration` is being raised because the generator expression has become exhausted (the expression's `yield` statement can't be run because the loop is  already terminated ) and Python raises in such a case `StopIteration`.

---

You can achieve wrapping of the generated sequence restarting from beginning and not raising StopIteration as follows:

```
nos = None

def generate_nos():
    global nos
    print(f"            CALL of generate_nos({nos=}):")
    while True: 
        nos = (i for i in range(10))
        for i in nos:
            print(f"                for i in {nos=}: {i=}, {i*2=}  (next line: yield i*2)")
            yield i * 2

loopCounter = 0
try:
    gen = generate_nos()
    while loopCounter < 22:
        loopCounter += 1
        nextGen = next(gen) 
        print(f'    INSIDE while(1):  {nextGen=} == next(gen)')
        if nextGen == 18:
            print(f"                    if nextGen == 18:  RUN NEXT ROUND OF i = 0..9")
except StopIteration:
    print(f"StopIteration:  {nos=}")

# > python3 -u "whyStopIteration.py"
#             CALL of generate_nos(nos=None):
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=0, i*2=0  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=0 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=1, i*2=2  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=2 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=2, i*2=4  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=4 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=3, i*2=6  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=6 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=4, i*2=8  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=8 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=5, i*2=10  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=10 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=6, i*2=12  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=12 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=7, i*2=14  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=14 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=8, i*2=16  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=16 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=9, i*2=18  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=18 == next(gen)
#                     if nextGen == 18:  RUN NEXT ROUND OF i = 0..9
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=0, i*2=0  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=0 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=1, i*2=2  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=2 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=2, i*2=4  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=4 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=3, i*2=6  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=6 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=4, i*2=8  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=8 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=5, i*2=10  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=10 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=6, i*2=12  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=12 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=7, i*2=14  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=14 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=8, i*2=16  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=16 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e500>: i=9, i*2=18  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=18 == next(gen)
#                     if nextGen == 18:  RUN NEXT ROUND OF i = 0..9
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=0, i*2=0  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=0 == next(gen)
#                 for i in nos=<generator object generate_nos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f2e8659e490>: i=1, i*2=2  (next line: yield i*2)
#     INSIDE while(1):  nextGen=2 == next(gen)
# > exit status: 0
```

if you don't wrap a global scope generator object with a generator function, but create the generator object within the function you are getting by you probably expected behavior.

To avoid trouble with running an endless loop the number of runs of the `while` loop is limited to 22 loop runs. You can see from the output that the generator function will now endlessly deliver values repeating the sequence of 0,2,4,...,18 again and again.

---

*Notice that in order to properly use a generator function in Python code you create a generator object `gen` using this function in first place in order to use this object later in the `next(gen)` statement to obtain a value.*

Answer (score -1):

`range` doesn't loop back to the start condition. Once all values from `range` have been iterated, it raises `StopIteration`. `(i for i in range(10))` is a generator that iterates the `range` object as it is iterated. When your generator returns 18, the underlying `range` object has returned 9 which is at the end of its range. The next iteration raises the exception.

It would be highly inconvenient if `range` didn't stop. Something like

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

would never stop.